# C# MysqlConnector works on one of my computers but not on another computer

Tags: c#, mysql, connection

I decided to widen my horizon and use C# (the free version) for a small program.
The program opens a mysql table and shows it's contents in a listview. I compile and run it on my developer machine and everything works fine. Then move it to my girlfriends computer. The application starts and the window appears but the list is empty.
Is there any limitation on the free version that prevents connection if it's running on another machine? It is the release compiled exe I'm trying to run.

Comment: Did you catch any exceptions?  I'm wondering if your database is configured on the other machine.

Comment: there is no limitation. there are many possibilities abut your problem. can you post the code you have written?

Comment: Both machines go for the same external database. The administration of the database is handled with a delphi program. That program can connect on both machines. Using the same ports, uids, passwords and database.

Comment: My machine is 64-bit and her machine is 32-bit. Another strange thing is that most of the time but not always. I compile the delphi program on my 64-bit machine and move the exe to her machine. It doesn't work, that is I can't connect to the database. However if I copy and compile the code on her machine it works always.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction that I know of. How are you handling exceptions? It's for more likely the environments don't match meaning you don't have MySQL or connections string isn't correct for the other computer.

If you're catching exceptions and suppressing the errors then you could easily be over looking exceptions with regard to the connection.

Comment: Never mind the question it was just the bone of my forehead being too thick. It was a port issue. I was fooled by the fact that delphi programs compiled on one machine not working and on another working.